# How to use ng-if else for the following nested json in angular 2?

Tags: angular, angular2-directives, angular-ng-if

I want to show hide certain fields in my form depending on the value of "visible" in the below json and dynamically show the names when "visible" is set to true.

my .json

```
{

"PanelInfo": {

"PersonalInformation": {

"DisplayName": "Personal Information",

"Activation": "True",

"Fields": {

"EmpCode": {

"DisplayName": "Emp Code",

"Visible": "True"

},

"Title": {

"DisplayName": "Title",

"Visible": "True"

},



"FirstName": {

"DisplayName": "First Name",

"Visible": "True"

},



"MiddleName": {

"DisplayName": "Middle Name",

"Visible": "False"

},



"LastName": {

"DisplayName": "Last Name",

"Visible": "False"

},



"FatherFName": {

"DisplayName": "Father First Name",

"Visible": "False"

},



"FatherMName": {

"DisplayName": "Father Middle Name",

"Visible": "True"

}

}

},



"ContactDetails": {

"DisplayName": "Contact Details",

"Activation": "False",

"Fields": {

"FatherLName": {

"DisplayName": "Father Last Name",

"Visible": "True"

},



"HusbandFName": {

"DisplayName": "Husband First Name",

"Visible": "True"

},



"HusbandMName": {

"DisplayName": "Husband Middle Name",

"Visible": "True"

},



"HusbandLName": {

"DisplayName": "Husband Last Name",

"Visible": "False"

},



"DateOfBirth": {

"DisplayName": "Date Of Birth",

"Visible": "False"

},



"MobileNo": {

"DisplayName": "Mobile No",

"Visible": "False"

},



"PassportNo": {

"DisplayName": "Passport No",

"Visible": "True"

},



"Qualification": {

"DisplayName": "Qualification",

"Visible": "True"

}

}

},



"OtherDetails": {

"DisplayName": "Passport,PAN,AADHAAR & OTHER DETAILS",

"Activation": "False",

"Fields": {

"OfficeEmail": {

"DisplayName": "Office Email",

"Visible": "True"

},



"PersonalEmail": {

"DisplayName": "Personal Email",

"Visible": "True"

},



"JoiningDate": {

"DisplayName": "Joining Date",

"Visible": "True"

},



"PermanentAddress1": {

"DisplayName": "Address1",

"Visible": "True"

},



"PermanentAddress2": {

"DisplayName": "Address2",

"Visible": "False"

},



"PermanentState": {

"DisplayName": "State",

"Visible": "False"

},



"PermanentCity": {

"DisplayName": "City",

"Visible": "True"

}



}

}

}

}
```

Comment: it does not seem to be an array

Comment: Please show us what you have done so far (.ts file and template). Also, which version of angular are you using?